# How to get dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

i want to access the dynamic generated id in jquery.but it not works in jquery but works in javascript.

my jquery code:

```
var img =  $("#MAP"+current_img_height);
 $("#map").css({'height': img.height + "px"});
```

my javascript code:

```
var img = document.getElementById("MAP" + current_img_height);
$("#map").css({'height': img.height + "px"});
```

what's wrong in my jquery code and how to get the dynamic id.
Any help will be greately appreciated

Comment: Why using jQuery when JavaScript works fine???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, if you are using `$('#MAP')[0]` you can able to get OBject.

```
        document.getElementById('#MAP');//Return DOM Object
        var img = $('#MAP')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object

        var img=$('#MAP'+current_img_height)[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

`img` is a jQuery object, not a dom element reference so it does not have the `height` property, it has a `height()` method so

```
$("#map").css({'height': img.height() + "px"});
```

or

```
$("#map").height(img.height());
```

Comment: it's works but my map background colour is changed.when click previous and next button.

Answer (score 0):

**As your code :**

```
$("#MAP"+current_img_height);
```

*(if current_img_height = 100)*

This is mean `$("#MAP100");` *(example : `<img id="MAP100">` *element with given id "MAP100"*

**If you want to get height from element :** do like this

```
var height =  $("#whateverID").height();
```

or

```
var height =  $(".whateverClass").height();
```